# How to add nested ul and li?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following response:

```
var resp = {
    name: "menu svc", // some basic info about the menu, not displayed in UI
    style: "topmenucontainer",
    childstyle: "topmenu",
    type: "MENU",
    "nodes": [{ // has the menu hierarchy info
        name: "Process",
        href: "some url",
        embedData: "true",
        instances: [{
            "title": "Proc1",
            "url": ""
        }, {
            "title": "Proc2",
            "url": ""
        }, {
            "title": "Proc3",
            "url": ""
        }],
        nodes: [{
            name: "Documents",
            href: "url3",
            embedData: "true",
            instances: [{
                "title": "Doc1",
                "url": "url1"
            }, {
                "title": "Doc2",
                "url": "url2"
            }],
            nodes: []
        }]
    }]
};
```

I have to basically create a menu structure as follows:

```
Process
   Proc1---------------->Documents
   Proc2                  Doc1-------------------------->
   Proc3                  Doc2
```

So,all the instances of a particular node will be listed as li under the node and each child node should be listed as ul inside each parent node instance.
Again, its a recursive structure as children node will contain grandchildren node ans should be displayed in the similar fashion.

Any pointer?

Thanks

Comment: `$('#header ul li').append('<ul></ul>')`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
$("#header ul").append('<li><ul><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul></li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
<ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, but i want to know ,can i get hold of last added li or ul and add the elements...something more generic ?

Comment: Hmm not sure what do you mean :) Can you explain better please?

Comment: Hi Alex, I am adding inner ul and lis depending on a service response.For the records returned by the response ,i need to create the ul and li tags. so, basically i don't know ,the number of nested ul or li tags.its driven by the response.

Comment: Can you post the response you get?

Comment: I have edited my post with response and requirement.